# create 10000 2dim arrays with a for loop with c#

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

Does some body how to create n(for example n=10000) arrays with a for loop which each array has its own index?
Array[,] number 1
Array[,] number 2
Array[,] number 3
.
.
.
I tried this code:

```
for (i=1;i<=10000;i++) { // create 2-dim array with index i }
```

Comment: Do you mean an array of arrays? Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: What problems are you experiencing? What have you tried?

Comment: for(i=0;i<=10000;i++) {  //create 2-dim array[,] with index i }

Comment: Then what!!! Edit  your question and provide more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an array of (2d) arrays.

```
int [][,] data = new int[10000][,];
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
   data[i] = new int[2,2];

data[z][x,y] = 123;
```

Comment: what if i don't want to use array of arrays? i mean a code like the one i tried.

Comment: Make that more concrete. In the question, not in the comments.